# How to splitt smart conract for reducing size of smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, proxy-contracts, optimization

Warning: Contract code size is 44924 bytes and exceeds 24576 bytes (a limit introduced in Spurious Dragon). This contract may not be deployable on Mainnet. Consider enabling the optimizer (with a low "runs" value!), turning off revert strings, or using libraries.

Comment: Read the [Downsizing contracts to fight the contract size limit](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/downsizing-contracts-to-fight-the-contract-size-limit/) tutorial on the Ethereum website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on your use case. There are many options.
In your case, the size of the contract is huge, so "**small**" saving tricks will not work. So I propose one of the following.

1. You might use **external** Libraries (You offload some logic there)
2. You separate logic into two or more contracts.
3. You might resort to using the [Dimond proxy pattern](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535) (which allows contracts of unlimited size)

**NOTE**: You should use a solidity optimizer during deployment/compiling contracts (That can lower the contract size by a considerable amount)

Comment: But if we don't have time to use the diamond proxy pattern for splitting client deadlines, the deadline is approaching. Therefore, I want to compose the smart contract into different contracts based on their size.

Comment: Quick question... Are you using a solidity optimizer during compilation? It can sometimes drop the size of your contract by 60%

Comment: yes i'm using this but i want to slove this for upcoming functions

Comment: Alright, but just so we are clear, your contract size is 44924 bytes WITH using optimizer in the compiler?

Comment: yes
Share more about it

Comment: In your case (One huge contract) it's either option 1 or option 2. It would depend on A LOT based on our business logic. It might be easiest to put some of the logic into an external library. https://jeancvllr.medium.com/solidity-tutorial-all-about-libraries-762e5a3692f9

If it would help we can arrange for a call, that way I might be able to assist/advise far better.